# How to use variable in a variable that has html

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I was wondering how I can use Variables in a Javascript variable that contains HTML for example in the code below

```
function SetCFonts()
{
    var Color = $('#CColor').val();
    var Font = $('#CFont').val();
    var Size = $('#CSize').val();
    var Bold = $('#CBoldOp').val();
    var Text = $('#NMsg').val();
    var Gen = "<font style=font-weight:+Bold color:+Color font-size:+Size font-family:+Font>Your Text Here</font>";

    alert(Gen);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using a font tag if you're setting the style in CSS (the right way)?

Comment: i'm making a text box where you can add a special font it will be put into mysql and displayed on another page

Comment: @MoussaHarajli - The `<font>` tag is deprecated and you shouldn't be using it: [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/font)

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings together:

```
var Gen = "<font style=font-weight:" +Bold + " color:" +Color + " font-size:"+Size + " font-family:" +Font+ ">Your Text Here</font>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an element out of it, and call jQuery's `.css()` method on it:

```
function SetCFonts ()
{
    var Gen = $('<font />').css({
        'color'         : $('#CColor').val(),
        'font-family'   : $('#CFont').val(),
        'font-size'     : $('#CSize').val(),
        'font-weight'   : $('#CBoldOp').val()
    }).text( $('#NMsg').val() );

    console.log( Gen );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use + operator like John Koerner answer.
Or you can also use [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) operator.

```
var Gen = "<font style=font-weight:".concat(Bold).concat("color:").concat(Color).concat("font-size:").concat(Size).concat("font-family:").concat(Font).concat(">").concat(Text).concat("</font>");
```

More detail :
[Multiple ways to concatenate a String in Javascript](http://sraji.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/multiple-ways-to-concatenate-a-string-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the concatenation: you have to close and reopen inverted commas:

```
function SetCFonts()
{
    var Color = $('#CColor').val();
    var Font = $('#CFont').val();
    var Size = $('#CSize').val();
    var Bold = $('#CBoldOp').val();
    var Text = $('#NMsg').val();
    var Gen = "<font style=font-weight:" + Bold + "; color:" + Color + "; font-size: " + Size + "; font-family: "+ Font +" >Your Text Here</font>";

    alert(Gen);
}
```